# Term+Fuzziness in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to use fuzzy with term query and not match? 
Let me explain:

suppose we have 4 documents

```
{ "index": { "_id": 1 }}
{ "text": "I play football!"}

{ "index": { "_id": 2 }}
{ "text": "I love playing"}

{ "index": { "_id": 3 }}
{ "text": "X is the best player"}

{ "index": { "_id": 4 }}
{ "text": "plyaer"}
```

when using :

```
GET /index/my_type/_search
{

"query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "value": "player",
      "fuzziness": 1 
    }
  }
}
```

I get :

```
{ "index": { "_id": 3 }}
{ "text": "X is the best player"}

{ "index": { "_id": 4 }}
{ "text": "plyaer"}
```

But I just want a result with plyaer which correspond to "exact" match("term") with fuzziness=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would require to have the field of type [Keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) whenever you do an exact match as, unlike [Text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) type, it won't go through the [Analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) phase

I've created below sample mapping where field `myfield` is a [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) as shown in below mapping.

**Mapping**

```
{  
   "myfield":{  
      "type":"text",
      "fields":{  
         "keyword":{  
            "type":"keyword",
            "ignore_above":256
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You can then perform the fuzzy search on the field of type `keyword` instead of `text` type.

**Fuzzy Query on myfield.keyword**

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "myfield.keyword": {
        "value": "player",
        "fuzziness": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can have the fuzzy query constructed for both types, with keyword type having *higher boost* so that such results with exact match appear at the top.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "myfield.keyword": {
              "value": "player",
              "fuzziness": 2,
              "boost": 10
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "myfield": {
              "value": "player",
              "fuzziness": 2,
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could I do the mapping after uploading my csv file to elasticsearch?

Comment: If you haven't created the mapping by yourself, Elasticsearch by default would create what I've mentioned in the mapping. A `text` and `keyword` twin would be created for every field that is categorised as string. If you have explicitly created the mapping then I'm afraid you would need to delete the existing index, create the index along with the mapping and insert the documents once again.